# is there a bootstrap to show icons from Fontastic?/ Font icon show as blank space

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I'm trying to use my owns icons instead of images on my site but when I load icons from Fontastic or Iconmoon it doesn't work neither in chrome or safari, do I need a bootstrap or there is a mistake in my code?

This is the CSS from Fontastic

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1";
  src:url("untitled-font-1.eot");
  src:url("untitled-font-1.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("untitled-font-1.woff") format("woff"),
    url("untitled-font-1.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("untitled-font-1.svg#untitled-font-1") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and how i tried to call the icon

```
<i class="icon-closeicon"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding a custom icon font (such as something from [icomoon](https://icomoon.io)) you have to do a few things.

- Import the font with [@font-face](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)
- Make sure you are importing the necessary css rules (**ex.** `.icon-location:before {content: "\e947";}`)
- Make sure your elements have the proper [`font-family`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) value (the icon font you just loaded)
- Make sure your elements have the correct `.class` name (the name of the icon you wish to call)

I have a suspicion that you are missing one of these steps (especially considering you didn't link the code in your question).

[Here is an example fiddle of how a complete import of an icon font should look.](http://jsfiddle.net/j4asr4mo/2/)